# Keras: How to subtract output of two different models and feed to another model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am getting same dimension outputs from different two models. I want to subtract those two outputs and give the result as an input to form a new model. But unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

> 'Subtract' object is not subscriptable

**My code:**

```
# create a data generator
datagen2 = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,brightness_range=[0.7,1.0],rotation_range=10,width_shift_range=[-10,10],preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
# load anad iterate training dataset
train_it2 = datagen2.flow_from_directory('DATA/train/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=50,subset='training',target_size=(224, 224),shuffle=True)
test_it2 = datagen2.flow_from_directory('DATA/val/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=50,target_size=(224, 224))
#subtract layer model

model_del1 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
#add layers
model_del1_x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), bias_regularizer=l2(0.002))(model_del1.output)
model_del1_x = Conv2D(4,(1,1), activation='relu')(model_del1_x)
model_del1_x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model_del1_x)

model_del1 = Model(inputs=model_del1.input, outputs=model_del1_x)
#print(model_del1.summary())


model_del2 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
#add layers
model_del2_x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), bias_regularizer=l2(0.002))(model_del2.output)
model_del2_x = Conv2D(4,(1,1), activation='relu')(model_del2_x)
model_del2_x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model_del2_x)

model_del2 = Model(inputs=model_del2.input, outputs=model_del2_x)
#print(model_del2.summary())

model_del_fin = keras.layers.Subtract()[model_del1_x, model_del2_x]

model_del_fin_x = Activation('softmax')(model_del_fin)
model_del_fin = Model(inputs=model_del_fin.input, outputs=model_del1_x)
print(model_del_fin.summary())
```

I Also tried `model_del_fin = keras.layers.Subtract()[model_del1.output, model_del2.output]` but got the same error.

Kindly, tell me the mistake I am making and also how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, `object[a]` always means: index into ('subscript') `object` via `a`; what you're looking for is to *call* `object` to trigger its [`call`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L401) method (and hence use it as a function):

```py
keras.layers.Subtract()[model_del1.output, model_del2.output]   # INCORRECT
keras.layers.Subtract()([model_del1.output, model_del2.output]) # CORRECT
```

This, however, will not solve the entire problem - which depends on intended usage; awaiting clarification.

---

**Update**: see comments; OP appears to have figured it out. To complete this answer: the goal is to *backpropagate* the subtracting model's outputs to the entire ensemble, including the two models whose outputs are subtracted.

Doing so requires a fully connected graph from each of the two models' `Input`s to the third model's output; e.g. `model3 = Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input], out)`. Data can then be fed as `model3.fit([x1, x2])`, or if `x1 == x2`, `model3.fit([x1, x1])`, where `x1` is fed to `model1.input`, `x2` is fed to `model2.input`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201989/discussion-on-answer-by-overlordgolddragon-keras-how-to-subtract-output-of-two).